# Image not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I want to display an image in my webpage, but it is not showing. Only the alt text is showing.

This is my code:

```
return (
        <>
            <div className="container my-5">
                <div className="row justify-content-start">
                    <div className="col-4">
                        <form>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">User name</label>
                                <input onChange={getUserName} value={userName} type="text" className="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Password</label>
                                <input onChange={getPassword} value={password} type="password" className="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" onClick={checkCreds} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-8">
                        <img src="img1.png" alt="picture" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

[This is being showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CVq3.png)

Comment: Is it in the same folder as the page being run?

Comment: yes, it is in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in the link of your image `src="img1.png"`, your image is not at this location. Check your console in the browser and your will certainly see a 404 error because the image cannot be found

Comment: I am not encountering such an error and I'm getting the same result if I use an image link

Answer (score 0):

You can check the developer tools browser to see if there were any errors loading the image. In Firefox press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There is two types of path declaration in html. Those are absolute and relative. In absolute path for example if we pass an URL it will be considered as an absolute path. On the other hand in relative path we declare the path relative to our folder structure. For example if our html file and the image file is in the same folder then your declaration is ok. Relative declaration depends on the root. If we store a picture one way forward, which means inside next folder from the root folder then from the root we have to reach to that folder by giving forward slash '/'. if the image in previous folder of root, then we have to move back by giving two dot and a slash '../'. You will get each and every details in the following link. Check your pictures folder placement and declare accordingly.

If all is ok then you can declare the root. './' will introduce that you are searching from the root. Like,

```html
<img src='./img1.png' alt='picture'>
```

[HTML file path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like below in the screenshot

[image]

And the result will be like below

[image]